# Dynamic SQL and carriage breaks

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert into a table with dynamic sql with the following code:

```
SET @SQLINSERT = 'INSERT INTO ' + @TABLENAME + ' (OP__DOCID, OP__PARENTID, OP__FOLDERID, CLIENTKEY, ADMISSIONKEY, PGMKEY, ' +
'PGMADMISSIONKEY, STAFFKEY, GroupSize, MealTime, AppMgrKey, SessionNum, FacilityKey, TtmNoteText,' + @DATEFIELD + ', ' + @TIMEFIELD + ') '

SET @SQLVALUES = 'VALUES (' + CAST(@NEWDOCID AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(@CLIENTKEY AS VARCHAR) + ', ' +
CAST(@CLIENTKEY AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(@CLIENTKEY AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(@ADMISSIONKEY AS VARCHAR) + ', ' +
ISNULL(CAST(@PGMKEY AS VARCHAR),'') + ', ' + ISNULL(CAST(@PGMADMISSIONKEY AS VARCHAR),'') + ', ' + CAST(@STAFFKEY AS VARCHAR) + ', ' +
    CAST(@GroupSize AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(@MealTime AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(@ApprvMgr AS VARCHAR) + ', ' 
    + CAST(@SessionNum AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + CAST(@FacilityKey AS VARCHAR) + ', ' --Added 10/30/15 JF for FC notes
    + @TtmNoteText +',' --Added 10/30/15 JF for FC notes    
    + 'NULL' + ', ' + 'NULL'  + ')'

EXEC(@SQLINSERT + @SQLVALUES)
```

And I want `@TtmNoteText` to include `char(10)` and `Char(13)` like the following

```
SET @TtmNoteText='Purpose Statement: '+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) --Added 10/30/15 JF for FC notes
    + 'Family Vision: '+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
    + 'Strengths: '+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
    + 'Challenges: '+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
    + 'Updates: '+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
    + 'Progress in Treatment Goals/ITFC Program: '+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
    + 'Services/Supports Needed: '+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)
    + 'Plan:'
```

I know that I am likely just not using the correct number of single quotes or something like that. Is it possible to insert with line/carriage breaks using dynamic sql

Answer (score 1):

Your entire `@SQLVALUES` variable is missing a lot of quotes. I'm not sure if this is perfectly accurate, but you need to put single quotes around your string values, but since you're building a dynamic statement, they need to be escaped (escape `'` with `'`):

```
SET @SQLVALUES = 'VALUES (''' + CAST(@NEWDOCID AS VARCHAR) + ''', ''' + CAST(@CLIENTKEY AS VARCHAR) + ''', ''' +
CAST(@CLIENTKEY AS VARCHAR) + ''', ''' + CAST(@CLIENTKEY AS VARCHAR) + ''', ''' + CAST(@ADMISSIONKEY AS VARCHAR) + ''', ''' +
ISNULL(CAST(@PGMKEY AS VARCHAR),'') + ''', ''' + ISNULL(CAST(@PGMADMISSIONKEY AS VARCHAR),'') + ''', ''' + CAST(@STAFFKEY AS VARCHAR) + ''', ''' +
    CAST(@GroupSize AS VARCHAR) + ''', ''' + CAST(@MealTime AS VARCHAR) + ''', ''' + CAST(@ApprvMgr AS VARCHAR) + ''', ''' 
    + CAST(@SessionNum AS VARCHAR) + ''', ''' + CAST(@FacilityKey AS VARCHAR) + ''', ''' --Added 10/30/15 JF for FC notes
    + @TtmNoteText +''',' --Added 10/30/15 JF for FC notes    
    + 'NULL' + ', ' + 'NULL'  + ')'
```

Secondly, I'm not sure you're allowed to use expressions within an `EXEC`. You might need to do some concatenation before passing to `EXEC`:

```
SET @SQLINSERT = @SQLINSERT + @SQLVALUES

EXEC(@SQLINSERT)
```